# Unity Build error: The name 'EditorUtility' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have got a very simple problem. I have a build error when I am trying to build my game in unity. When I run the game in the editor it works just fine. Here is the error as it is shown in the console.

```
Assets\Scripts\Pattern.cs(284,17): error CS0103: The name 'EditorUtility' does not exist in the current context
```

Now, this is the line of code the error was referencing to:

```
EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Great!", "You got the pattern right!", "Next Level!");
```

Lastly, if you think the error is that I didn't import the right things into the script then you are wrong because I imported this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEditor;
```

can anybody help me? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
doing this code:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Meh", "You got the pattern wrong ):", "Try Again!");
#endif
```

doesn't work. In the build version it just doesn't show the message box and it acts as though this line is just a comment. Can somebody help?

Comment: You can't use Editor classes in your runtime code. Move the script to an Editor folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why you have errors now is, Unity remove "UnityEditor" namespace in compile time as they designed for it. That is why when you try to use it on platform, "EditorUtility" will never exist on any platform except UnityEditor. Because "EditorUtility" is in "UnityEditor" namespace.

so if you want do same jobs as you did in Unity editor using "EditorUtility" you should implement it your own as they do.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Great!", "You got the pattern right!", "Next Level!");
#else
    YOUROWNCLASS.DisplayDialog("Great!", "You got the pattern right!", "Next Level!");
#endif
```

Comment: wasn't exactly this already answered two hours ealier by the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56813862/7111561)?

Answer (score 4):

`UnityEditor` content is typically only available for use in the Editor, as in, you can't use it when building your game as a standalone EXE.

Try adding preprocessor directives to *only* include the Editor-related stuff if you're actually compiling your game for the Editor.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Great!", "You got the pattern right!", "Next Level!");
#endif
```

You also need to put the same `#if UNITY_EDITOR ... #endif` directives around your `using UnityEditor;` line, as @Retired Ninja informed us in the comments.

Comment: You do need to put the ifdefs around the using.

Comment: But I should mention: From the looks of that text, this is supposed to be a player-facing dialog? `EditorUtility.DisplayDialog()` will only work if you're in editor mode, so it won't be useful for anyone actually playing the game. You should look into making your own dialogs using Unity UI

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja!

Comment: Wait guys, the build finished successfully but the message box didn't show up. It was like these lines are just comments. can somebody help?

Comment: @INTODAN That's exactly the idea of the preprocessor directives, it makes it so those lines don't occur during the gameplay at all (*unless* you're playing in the Editor). You can't use `EditorUtility` when you're not in the editor, you'll need to find some other way to display dialogs, unfortunately

Comment: @INTODAN is there a special reason why you accepted the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56814336/7111561) instead of this one though this answer was added 2 hours before the other answer?

Comment: @derHugo I figure it's because I didn't initially specify that one would have to use a different approach, like designing your own DisplayDialog() method, since the EditorUtility wouldn't work outside of the editor. That's just my guess though